# Is this a valid use of fgetc?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, nested-loops, fgetc

My input stream is from a text file with a list of words separated by the \n character. 
The function stringcompare is a function that will compare the equivalence of two strings, case insensitive.

I have two string arrays, word[50] and dict[50]. word is a string that would be given by the user. 
Basically what I want to do is pass word[] and each word in the text file as arguments of the stringcompare function.

I've compiled and run this code but it is wrong. Very wrong. What am I doing wrong? Can I even use fgetc() like this? would dict[] even be a string array after the inner loop is done?

```
        char c, r;
        while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF){ 
            while((r = fgetc(in)) != '\n'){
                dict[n] = r;
                n++;

            }
            dict[n+1] = '\0'; //is this necessary?
            stringcompare(word, dict);
        }
```

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`, your `c` is a `char`. So not, it's not valid. To read lines from a stream, I suggest you use `fgets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is wrong.

- The return value of `fgetc()` should be stored to `int`, not `char`, especially when it will be compared with `EOF`.
- You might forgot to initialize `n`.
- You will miss the first character of each line, which is stored to `c`.
- Use `dict[n] = '\0';` instead of `dict[n+1] = '\0';` because `n` is already incremented in the loop.

Possible fix:

```
int c, r;
while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF){ 
    ungetc(c, in); // push the read character back to the stream for reading by fgetc later
    n = 0;
    // add check for EOF and buffer overrun for safety
    while((r = fgetc(in)) != '\n' && r != EOF && n + 1 < sizeof(dict) / sizeof(dict[0])){
        dict[n] = r;
        n++;

    }
    dict[n] = '\0'; //this is necessary
    stringcompare(word, dict);
}
```

Comment: I think it could also loop forever if the first char is a newline.

Comment: Can you also explain why return value of `fgetc()` should be stored in `int`?

Comment: Because `fgetc()` return `int` value, and `EOF` won't fit in `char`.

Comment: Detail:  If `char` is signed and `EOF == -1`, The value `EOF` _does_ fit in a `char`.  The trouble is `fgetc()` returns values in the range `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  This is typically 257 different values which cannot be stored distinctly in a `char` and so the `EOF` loses distinction with one of the `char`, hence the need for `int`.  Also, as you say, `EOF` may not be in the range of `char`.